# No available data in data Table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatables

I'm unable to get a php pdo ajax with data tables to populate. It simply says "No data available in table."

My thinking here is that my php script is not working or either the script is not working either. I am trying to understand everything in the fetch.php but it doesn't go well ://

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#dataTable').DataTable({
  "processing":true,
  "serverSide":true,
  "order":[],
  "ajax":{
   url:"fetch.php",
   type:"POST"
  },
  "columnDefs":[
   {
    "targets":[5, 6],
    "orderable":false,
   },
  ],
 })
});
</script>
```

fetch.php

```
<?php
include('../includes/db.php');

$query = '';
$output = array();
$query .= "SELECT * FROM prefect_reports";
if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
 $query .= 'WHERE stud_id LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
 $query .= 'OR stud_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
 $query .= 'OR stud_grade_sec LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
 $query .= 'OR acad_year LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
 $query .= 'OR rec_date LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
}

$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$data = array();
$filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
foreach($result as $row)
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = $row['stud_id'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['stud_name'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['stud_grade_sec'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['acad_year'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['rec_date'];
 $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row['rec_id'].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Update</button>';
 $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row['rec_id'].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Delete</button>';
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}
$output = array(
 "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "recordsTotal"  =>  $filtered_rows,
 "recordsFiltered" => get_total_all_records(),
 "data"    => $data
);
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

db.php

```
<?php
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$connection = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=rcss', $username, $password );
?>
```

index.html with bootstrap 4

```
<script src="../vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<script src="../js/demo/datatables-demo.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered"  width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Student ID</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Grade/Section</th>
                <th>Academic Year</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Student ID</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Grade/Section</th>
                <th>Academic Year</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried to add to output the arrays but it doesn't work

```
"recordsTotal"  =>  $filtered_rows,
 "recordsFiltered" => get_total_all_records(),
```

Im looking for the easiest approach that can populate the data from phpmyadmin sql to datatables bootstrap

Comment: So what does your request to the fetch.php actually return, check that using your browser dev tools.

Comment: And btw., you are open to SQL injection there - if you insert outside data _directly_ into your WHERE clause, then preparing the statement afterwards will _not_ help you against that.